# Facebook Graph API - get postst posted by my aplication

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-sdk-3.0

How to compose request which is retrieve wall posts posted by my application or at least I want to get ALL posts posted by any application or user. Now I can see only posts from myself and friends : `me?fields=feed` with permission `read_stream`. If it impossible with`Graph API` how to do this with `FQL` ?

Answer (score 0):

select message from stream where source_id = DESTINATION ID and app_id= YOUR APP ID

If you want to filter by stuff your app is posting you have to find the id that your app is posting on. This is the "soure_id" ie where your post is going. Then you just have to add the parameter of what your app_id is that your app is posting as. If you wanted to filter by user you would just insert their uid as the actor_id instead of app_id.